# Fade out before loading new content

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I fade out #special, then load the content, and when it´s loaded fade in again.

```
function test(x,y) {
    $('#special').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#special').load('index.php?close=1 #special');     
}
```

I don´t want it to display/load the new content until #special has faded out.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `fadeIn()` inside the `load()` callback, which runs after it's loaded:

```
$('#special').fadeOut('fast');
$('#special').load('index.php?close=1 #special', 
                   function() { $('#special').fadeIn('slow'); });
```

Comment: I don't want it to load until it has faded out.

Comment: @Daniel: Then call `load` in the `fadeOut` callback.

Comment: Can you update this to also include that suggestion? (calling load in the fadeout) it would make this a better dupe target.